# Convert a gene sequence file to a qr code?

Tags: python

Is it possible to convert a text file using python comprising of a string of just letters 'A', 'T', 'C', 'G' to a qr code such that the the different letters are encoded in different colored pixels ?
Note : The text file is usually massive. More than 100 MB

Comment: Do you _really_ want a QR code (which would be huge, and not conform to the QR standards, as llogiq has explained). OR do you just want a giant 4 color rectangular image that encodes the ATCG data?

Comment: The "different colored pixels" are for *two* colors only, not four. Besides, that's not really how QR codes work anyway.

Comment: @Jongware: FWIW, conforming QR codes _can_ contain more than two colors, but the additional colors can't be used to convey data: they're only cosmetic.

Comment: I'm aware of that. The parameters of the color separation algorithm are described in excruciating detail in the original specifications. For the OP: while it means that you *may* use red, blue, yellow, and white, all a QR scanner is interested in is 'dark' and 'light'. So you'd loose exactly half of your (intended) information.

Comment: @Jongware: Sure. You'd have to encode the ATCG data as pairs of bits in the usual way, and add the color info on top of that. But of course, it's still **extremely** impractical for the amount of data the OP is talking about!

Answer (score 2):

Note that the usual QR codes – even when using Version 40 with 117x117 "pixels" only can store a bit more than a kilobyte of data (due to error correction and other features).

100MB of fasta data, even if compressed, will consume more than 10MB. That's only a few orders of magnitude, so you could either (in theory) construct a QR code (that would need to be a few meters across) or use *a lot* of them.

Answer (score 1):

Create your own System, you can't store 100Mb in QR.
Why save gene sequence in QR ? Zip it and send it.